# Mails to Microsoft's servers rejected

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, postfix, spam-prevention, blacklist

When I send an email to any Microsoft address it's instantly rejected.

Searching for a while I find that only MS servers blacklist my IP, and I need to go to JMRP and ask them to remove it: https://postmaster.live.com/snds/JMRP.aspx

I signed in, and added my IP, the status shows that it's blocked, but can't find any link to request a removal..

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: No one can help!! Up!!

Answer (score -1):

We are a small ISP, today we had the very same problem, go to this link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=614866 (from their FAQ https://postmaster.live.com/snds/FAQ.aspx#FeedbackAndQuestions) and complete the request form

they told us we have been "conditionally mitigated" (unblacklisted) and finally our emails to their accounts gets delivered, still marked as "junk": we are still not able to know why our mailserver IP has been blacklisted, we are still waiting for a complete reply, if we'll evet get it

ciao
Giovanni